# Explicit constructor char* vs string literal

Tags: c++, explicit

So I was updating some code to use explicit and ran into seemingly inconsistent behavior in something like this:

```
explicit Whatever(const wchar_t* const pszVal)
```

This doesn't work with a literal string which has a type of const wchar_t[x], and explicit prevents it from being accepted in the above constructor. It complains that

> const wchar_t[x] cannot be converted to const wchar_t* const

.

But, if I add one for the array scenario:

```
explicit Whatever(const wchar_t pszVal[])
```

Then it claims this constructor already exists and that it is the above constructor that won't accept the array form. So it seems like a catch-22 that would prevent me from having an explicit constructor for literal strings.

This is Visual C++ 2017. Am I missing something here? I'd be happy to provide the extra constructor of course, but it appears to be acting inconsistently.

---

OK, just to follow up, since this wouldn't work in a comment very easily, the scenarios is this:

```
class AString { Whatever(const wchar_t* const val) {} } ;
class Something { Something(const AString& val) {} };
```

Creating a Something passing a literal fails, because it won't convert L"X" into AString :

```
Something MySomething(L"X");
```

Obviously is a different thing from what I was thinking, but unexpected to me. AString has a valid constructor to take a wchar_t. Why wouldn't the above just create a temporary?

If that's how explicit really is supposed to work, it's sort of semi-useless since you could never make any fundamental classes of this sort explicit if you wanted to take parameters of that type but pass in things that you explicitly said you want that class to accept, right?

Comment: You probably need a `template<size_t n> explicit Whatever(const wchar_t pszVal[n]);` overload.

Comment: I could do that. I just never want to throw in hacks because something that seems like it should work isn't working. I was just making sure that that otherwise seemingly very benign conversion would really stop working with explicit. And it's more than a conversion I think, normally aren't they treated as literally the same when passed as a parameter? Which would seem to be upheld by the fact that the same rejected type becomes a duplicate type in the second scenario. That just seemed wrong to me.

Comment: `explicit` isn't for exact types in constructor arguments, it's to prevent the set of arguments from implicitly being converted to the type being constructed.

Comment: Sure, but that's not really the issue at hand. The issue is that it normally is accepted, and not only that, if you then use it directly in another ctor variation it's treated as a duplicate of the type that it say cannot accept that type (the first variation.) That seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: I also can't reproduce your first error with [this online MSVC version](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9xh98o). The second is because `T[]` in a parameter list is adjusted to `T*`.

Comment: Perhaps the constness is involved?

Comment: The second `const` in the first declaration should be ignored.  And because function parameters with array type are transformed to be pointer type instead, those two declarations do in fact declare the same constructor.  I can't think of any explanation for the first quoted error message.  Can you provide a [mcve] that results in that error?

Comment: You know the compiler gods aren't gonna be that nice to me.. I'll try it later but I'm guessing it's just going to sit across the aisle and make fun of me.

Comment: OK, I figured out what is going on, though I'm still sort of surprised about it. I updated the original post to explain the actual issue. Is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Well, some more digging and that is indeed how it works. It's really backwards from what I was thinking. It's strange that you so often seeing people say, you should make all your single parameter ctors explicit unless there's some specific reason not to. But that would never work with classes like strings or number wrappers or anything like that, since it would cause the above problem and then require explicit casting for the only actual types you really want them to take.

Comment: @DeanRoddey: "*this wouldn't work in a comment very easily, the scenarios is this:*" Um, which one of those constructors is supposed to be explicit? Because after fixing all of the compiler bugs in your example (`AString` not having a constructor, everything being *private*. Make sure your example is a [mcve] before you post), it []works just fine](https://www.ideone.com/lm6jRM).

Comment: Oh, I wasn't trying to provide working code. Just indicating the scenario that was failing wasn't the one I original thought. It was indirect.So I see what's happening and read up some more and it's what is to be expected. That's why I didn't post working code, since I already knew what was going on.

Comment: @DeanRoddey: See the "delete" link at the bottom of your question? If this question no longer serves a purpose, then you should use that.